# Having problems with Classes. Any Random result is coming when I am multiplying two numbers.

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class area
{
public:
    int l,b;
    int enter()
    {
    cout<<"Enter Length: ";
    cin>>l;
    cout<<"Enter Breadth: ";
    cin>>b;
    }
};

class rectangle : public area

{
public:
    int arr()
    {
        cout<<"Area of Rectangle is: "<<l*b;
    }

};


    int main ()
    {
        area obj;
        rectangle ob;
        obj.enter();
        ob.arr();
    }
```

I am able to enter the values but the result is shown as "344765440". Tell me if there is anything wrong with my code. And I also cannot use inheritance properly. I cannot use the object of "area" class.

Comment: `int enter()` `int main()` `int arr()`. You are not returning any integer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first basic problem to solve is that your functions do not return anything but are declared to return `int`. Fix this by turning them into `void` functions; otherwise, you are running into **undefined behaviour**.

Getting seemingly random output is a common result of undefined behaviour, although in this case it's very likely caused by another instance of undefined behaviour.

In order to find that other instance of undefined behaviour, let's start by looking at this piece of code:

> ```
>    area obj;
>     rectangle ob;
> ```

This creates **two different `area` objects**.

- First, you create `obj`, which is just an `area`.
- Second, you create `ob`, which is a `rectangle` and thus contains another `area` as a subobject.

`l` and `b` are left uninitialised in both `area` objects.

Then you call the member functions...

> ```
>    obj.enter();
> ```

This sets the `l` and `b` data members in the first `area` object.

> ```
>  ob.arr();
> ```

This attempts to read from the still uninitialised `l` and `b` data members in the second `area` object (the subobject of `rectangle`). Attempting to read from an uninitialised `int` is, again, **undefined behaviour**.

What you have to do is creating only a `rectangle` object, which already contains an `area`. Do *not* create a separate `area` object!

Here is a modified version of your code with both fixes:

```
#include <iostream>

class area
{
public:
    int l;
    int b;
    void enter()
    {
    std::cout<<"Enter Length: ";
    std::cin>>l;
    std::cout<<"Enter Breadth: ";
    std::cin>>b;
    }
};

class rectangle : public area

{
public:
    void arr()
    {
        std::cout<<"Area of Rectangle is: "<<l*b;
    }

};


int main ()
{
    rectangle ob;
    ob.enter();
    ob.arr();
}
```

---

You might also want to reconsider your use of inheritance and review your understanding of object-oriented theory. Remember, public inheritance has the meaning of *is-a*. Do you think that a rectangle *is* an area? I'd say a rectangle *has* an area. Has-a relationships should be expressed with membership, i.e. by `rectangle` having an `area` data member.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was just revising C++ after a while. This code works. Thanks again. Much Appreciated !.

Answer (score 0):

**This is because the with help of enter() function you are setting attributes of class area. And you are calling function arr() of class rectangle.
Thus the attributes of class rectangle are not set, and it will random answer.**

try the following code, It will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class area
{
public:
    int l,b;
    int enter()
    {
    cout<<"Enter Length: ";
    cin>>l;
    cout<<"Enter Breadth: ";
    cin>>b;
    }
};

class rectangle : public area

{
public:
    int arr()
    {
        cout<<"Area of Rectangle is: "<<l*b;
    }

};


    int main ()
    {
        area obj;
        rectangle ob;
        ob.enter();
        ob.arr();
    }
```